# How to refine the results obtained from a search

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I am using SQL Server 2000 and ASP.Net with c# for making a search engine.

I want to refine the results obtained from a search without making server connections again and again due to speed factor.

How can I make my search faster? How can I make fewer connections?

Comment: Please clarify.  Are you trying to avoid the HTTP client reconnecting to your server, or avoid unnecessary SQL queries, or something else?

Comment: i want to avoid unnecessary SQL queries

Comment: can u give me another suggestion ......Searock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Matthew alluded to, your two connection points are the HTTP request from the client (web browser) to the server (web server), and the connection from the web server to the sql server.

The connection from the web server to the sql server costs very little in the whole client-server-sql-server-client trip.  So one would assume you are talking about the browser-to-webserver connection.  Only way to avoid that is to dump the entire database (or at least the unfiltered pool of records one can query) to the browser and do your filtering client-side - which is an INCREDIBLY !!BAD!! IDEA.

So my suggestion would be to stop fretting, write the application as you normally would, and if things are looking slow when you are done then you can start looking for where the slowness is comming from - instead of trying to guess (and probably be wrong) before there's even an issue.

Comment: but my application responding slow........
i just want to minimise the connection with the sql server......
do u hv ny idea.........

Comment: I think you may need to tell us why the application is responding slow? what is causing the slowness? Maybe if you can identify what the actual problem is then we may be able to help.

Comment: i am describing my application..
in my application i am searching properties for a particular city and afer this search there is options of refinement of results with the localities, bedrooms and cover area options each time a generate a query for each refinement...
now what can i do.........?

Comment: i am already added appropriate indexesin my database i am also using full text indexing.......

Comment: and how do you know they are appropriate?